# Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS and mainline kernels

Tags: kernel, dependencies

I'm running an Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS on an Intel 11th gen CPU. The problem I have is that I need to install kernel 5.12.X in order to be able to use the iGPU for rendering. The problem of course, is that looks like there is a dependency issue with the kernel header and the LTS version:

```
linux-headers-5.12.9-051209-generic : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is installed
```

I don't have enough background knowledge to compile the kernel myself and so far, that's the only way I found on internet to solve this dependency issue.

1. Is there any other/n00b way to solve this issue? (i don't feel comfortable installing a 3rd party ppa kernel out there)
2. Is there any place where I can check which is the latest kernel compatible with my Intel UDH 750 iGPU that has not this dependency issue?

Sorry for so many question. I'm doing baby steps on linux, and every time it happens this kind of things, I'm always worried to break everything...

Comment: So I recently had issues with some older hardware that wasn't able to work graphically well with the 5.12.* kernel, granted they were using 20.10 & 21.04 they just seemed to not click. What I advise mainly is to keep installed atleast some older kernel's incase the kernel you install starts locking up or freezing. In mainline you may get errors about missing header files, I did too especially in 20.04 -> kernel 5.12.* however those should be fixed with apt update, --fix-broken, autoremove, upgrade.

Comment: doing that, you will just remove the linux-headers-5.12.9-051209-generic and you will have a broken installation. Not recommended.

Comment: --fix-broken install is going to fix any broken packages, autoremove is going to remove any unneeded packages. I've updated to 5.12 kernel multiple times on multiple devices, never have those commands broken them, what did I do that you aren't doing?

Comment: You could try to manually install libc6 version 2.33, but it seems like you have the answers for everyone trying to help, so why are you in this predicament?

Comment: Also iGPU rendering is definitely available below Kernel 5.12.*. I'm not sure what your issue is and maybe the recommendation is to revert to an older Kernel..

Comment: Thanks Gloat, I appreciate the time you took for replying to my msg, but unfortunately doesn't answer any of my questions. --fix-broken will remove the header and it's not possible to install libc6 2.33 on 20.04 LTS. Last version is 2.31. There is already an open discussion and a bug reported for this issue on the ubuntu launchpad. If you really want to help me, please read again my questions. There is no need to provide a solution, if you don't have it and it's completely understandable. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: In case you want to do some reading and learn about this issue: [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1926938)

Comment: My apologies for not having read that issue prior, I see now why the autoremove would cause issues. So your graphics driver won't work on previous kernel versions? I read in other posts to check `prime` but that would usually be when you have a Nvidia dGPU as well in there.
Again my apologies for the novice and potentially negative approach I suggested, that's what I was using when I had issues updating my kernel from 5.11 to 5.12.

Comment: No choice for you mate, you're going to either compile your own, or move to a rolling distro like Fedora or openSUSE Tumbleweed which tracks mainline automatically.

Answer (score 0):

People on mint forum and this site recommend installing this package "linux-oem-20.04b", but i think you will need to use default Ubuntu 20.04 kernels.

```
sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04b
```

Comment: The problem is that I will not be able to use my hardware due to the lack of drivers.

Comment: So you tried this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay on my reply. Yes I tried that too but it doesn't work properly unfortunately. Using oem kernel 5.10 while rendering, the output is full of glitches and artifacts. I assume the whole eco-system is just not ready for the last intel gen cpus...